# Document Library and Content Type issue. Getting set as Folder for few files

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, content-type

I have a Document Library with Content Type enabled. I have few custom columns. I have not used any Custom content type.By default content type is Document.

Issue is when i add some files i do not get Edit form to set all the field values and the content type gets stored as Folder. I am uploading `.docx, .xlsx, .pptx` files.

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

The file is a .ppt file but the Content Type is set as Folder. If i download this file and add in a replicated library in some other site collection than also the Content Type remains as Folder.

Comment: Could u share screenshot for ur list setting page and the library default view.

Comment: @Pushpendra i have updated my question body with the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible issues here:

In some documents that are either a 2007 or 2010 format there is an issue with the properties. If you go to file>properties>advanced properties>custom field then you will see an entry called content type id. By removing content type id from custom fields then documents that are loaded in either 2007 or 2010 format will have the correct content type.

The second issue is that some of your documents are created in a version earlier than 2007. Office 2007 is the earliest version of Office that works well with Sharepoint 2010. If you save these files into either 2007 or 2010 version of Office then that will resolve the issue.

Comment: @Ishan Could you please tell me if it was the first or the second paragraph that resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me:

http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2011/10/19/sharepoint-default-library-content-type-is-folder.aspx

In my case it was about removing all Content Types from the library first, and then adding my custom ones. It caused SharePoint to set the "Folder" Content Type as default, even though the Content Type list says another thing.